# Get the users that my following users are following

Tags: php, user-meta, users

I have a social site that contains follow users system.

Each user has two custom meta:

- following_users
- followers_users

My question how can get the users that my following users are following?

I try something like this but it's not working:

```
$get_the_following_users = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'following_users', true);
foreach ( $get_the_following_users as $following_user ) {
    $following_user = get_user_meta($following_user, 'following_users', true);

    $meta_qssuery .= $following_user.', ';
}

echo $meta_qssuery;
```

Note: I store the array meta of following_users and followers_users like this:

```
a:8:{i:9;i:9;i:57;i:57;i:3;i:3;i:71;i:71;i:85;i:85;i:89;i:89;i:152;i:152;i:2;i:2;}
```

Comment: you're adding the ids of the current user's followers to your output, and not the ids of the followers of the current user's followers.

Comment: @inarilo sorry it's a mistake I edited now the question and try again it's print to me Array, Array, Array, Array, (i think I must use another foreach but I cant do this i need a help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to concatenate array elements:

```
$get_the_following_users = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'following_users', true);
$meta_qssuery = ''; //initialise to an empty string
foreach ( $get_the_following_users as $following_user ) {
    $following_user = get_user_meta($following_user, 'following_users', true);

    if(!empty($following_user)) { //check if any data was returned
        $meta_qssuery .= implode(', ', $following_user).', ';
    }
}

echo $meta_qssuery;
```

This will leave an extra ', ' at the end of the string. This can be removed after the loop ends, or you can modify the loop:

```
$get_the_following_users = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'following_users', true);
$get_the_following_users_2 = array();
foreach ( $get_the_following_users as $following_user ) {
    $following_user = get_user_meta($following_user, 'following_users', true);

    if(!empty($following_user)) { //check if any data was returned
        $get_the_following_users_2[] = implode(', ', $following_user);
    }
}

$meta_qssuery = implode(', ', $get_the_following_users_2);
echo $meta_qssuery;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's getting the users that I follow not the users that my following users follow to solve this change the variable name of $get_the_following_users from $meta_qssuery and  $get_the_following_users[$i]

Comment: another thing if there are no results you will get this error: Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in this line ($meta_qssuery = implode(', ', $get_the_following_users);). please solve this.

Comment: i did not consider a scenario where there are no results, in which case the original array `$get_the_following_users` remained unchanged. I have modified the code to use a separate array variable instead,.